# can one load remote url in bootstrap 5 modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to load a remote file (on the same server and folder) in a bootstrap 5 modal popup. Is this possible? I read that it could be done with bootstrap 3 but I need it to work using bootstrap 5.

Comment: "Is it possible?" isn't a good question for SO. Please see [ask].

Comment: If you read that _it could be done with Bootstrap 3_ then, try it with 5 because it should work. And if you stuck with something after you have tried, then ask here.